# Select Dinámico en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy trabajando en un sistema en el cuál, en un formulario tengo un `select` para seleccionar datos de una tabla, y en la vista del formulario me funciona ya que me carga todos los datos que tengo almacenados en dicha tabla; pero cuando selecciono una de las opciones, sea cual séa la que seleccione, siempre se guarda el primer registro de la tabla... Es como que toma solamente el primer registro de la tabla.

El código que tengo en el formulario es:

```
<select name="servicio"  >
   <option disabled selected>Seleccione el tipo de Servicio</option>
   @foreach($servicio as $s)
   <option value="{{$s->servicio}}">{{$s->servicio}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

siendo el controlador:

```
public function create()
{
   $servicio = Servicio::all();
   return view('tramites.create', compact('servicio'));
}
```

Recalco que en el formulario las opciones se despliegan con los datos que tengo almacenados en la tabla, pero si selecciono por ejemplo, la tercera opción, selecciona siempre la primera.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que comprendas un poco mas como funciona el sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). También te invito a revisar [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mas completa. Cuando vas a guardar es que solo te toma el primer valor?

Comment: `<option disabled selected>Seleccione el tipo de Servicio</option>` en esta opción quita el atributo `selected` y valida si ahora puedes guardar otra opción. Quedaría así: `<option disabled>Seleccione el tipo de Servicio</option>`

Comment: @CesarRomero gracias por tu comentario, en el ejemplo lo puse así pero en realidad el **selected** ya no lo estoy utilizando, pero de igual forma me sigue seleccionando siempre el primero

Comment: estará el problema en el código que guarda el registro?

Comment: `public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'factura', 'cliente', 'fecha', 'direccion', 'rtn', 'servicio'
        ]);
        $tramite = new Tramite($request->all());
        $tramite->save();
        return redirect('/tramites');
    }`

Comment: ese es el codigo que uso en el controlodor para almacenar